# Invalid JSON inside .ajax() function error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

In my $.ajax I have

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            alert(result.ErrorMessage);
  }
```

Even though this has worked for all my previous apps, this time this choked and gave me an invalid JSON error. I am using jQuery 1.5, asp.net MVC 3.

PS:  I looked at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) but I didn't see the example of what JSON consumed by `error` should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value in `xhr.reponseText`? Just print it out using console.log(). Unless you are formatting your error pages as JSON, you're probably getting some standard 500 HTML from the server, that's why you can't parse it as JSON.

jQuery does not dictate the `responseText` that is returned by the server in case of an error

Comment: My bad, I neglected to add a handler to the controller action. The handler is the routine that formats the JSON properly.